# Empty cart upon page load allowing add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to create a one-page landing page with a product and checkout.

When the page is loaded I want the cart to empty.
But I want to be able to add to cart, and checkout on the same page.

I want to achieve this only on pages with a specific page-template.

I'm working from *[Clear Woocommerce Cart on Page Load Even for logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254862/clear-woocommerce-cart-on-page-load-even-for-logged-in-users/55257594#55257594)* answer code.

This is what I have:

```
?>
<?php 
//epmty cart
if (! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
    WC()->cart->empty_cart( true );
}
<?php 
// show add to cart button
echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart id='22']');
?>
// allow checkout Even though Cart Is Empty
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review_expired', '__return_false' );
?>
<?php 
echo do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_checkout' );
?>
```

The problem I think is that the page refreshes upon add to cart and therefor empties the cart again. How do I make it run only once? or is there a better way to clear the cart?

Comment: yes, it is enabled

Comment: I haven't found yet the way to restrict that for only a custom template page…

Comment: Would the code work directly in the template?

Comment: Updated my answer… You can try that or use my answer new way… I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

You could try the following code in your template:

```
$current_product_id = 22; // The product ID 
$cart               = WC()->cart; // The WC_Cart Object

// When cart is not empty 
if ( ! $cart->is_empty() ) {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // If the cart item is not the current defined product ID
        if( $current_product_id != $cart_item['product_id'] ) {
            $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key ); // remove it from cart
        }
    }
} 
// When cart is empty
else {
    // allow checkout Event
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart', '__return_false' );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review_expired', '__return_false' );
}

// show add to cart button
echo do_shortcode( "[add_to_cart id='22']");

// show Checkout
echo do_shortcode( "[woocommerce_checkout]" );
```

Comment: Great - but since functions.php is general I'd need to make "// Keep only last item added to cart" conditional to a specific page template. Is this posible?

Comment: @tiny Update 2 … I found another way that could work… Try it and told me.